# Which element to find to go to next webpage?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

Trying to make a web scraper/web crawler however I can't seem to find the correct way to find the element for the first recommended video in this [shutterstock page](https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-16591042-minsk-belarus---aug-31-2015-ungraded). I've tried all of the possible ways to try to get to it but it always ends up being infinite (or at least very long) or it doesn't return anything back.

Here is the current code that I have.

````py
        while vid_count < num_vids:
        actual_vid_link = wd.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'source')
        print("Added - " + actual_vid_link.get_attribute('src'))
        vid_links.add(actual_vid_link.get_attribute('src'))

        vid_count = len(vid_links)

        if len(vid_links) >= num_vids:
            print(f"Found: {len(vid_links)} video links, done!")
            break
        else:
            wd.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "jss996")[0].click()```
````

Comment: what do you mean next webpage? you should demonstrate your question clearly

Comment: are you asking how to get to the "Similar videos" page or how to get to the page of the first similar video?

Comment: @Driftr95 How to get to the page of the first similar video. Sorry for the confusion. I'm at my wits and can't figure out how I'm going to find the element.

Comment: @miguel-flores06 try `wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'MuiGrid-root jss969 MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-4 MuiGrid-grid-sm-6').find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').click()` but only for this page I think - the `jss969` bit seems to vary

Comment: @miguel-flores06 if you mean first similar video *on the "similar videos" page* [after clicking "See More"], try `[a for a in wd.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a') if a.get_attribute('href') and a.get_attribute('href').startswith('/video/clip-')][0].click()`

Comment: `wd.find_element(By.cssSelector("a[href^=’/video/clip-’]")).click()` is more readable...